# Reference for forcing using topos theory

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, forcing, topos-theory

I've just saw in Maclane and Moerdijik's book ("Sheaves in Geometry and Logic: A First Introduction to Topos Theory") about the Cohen forcing  viewed in a categorical way using Topos theory. Is there any reference for forcing techniques using categories and Topos? Can the other kinds of forcing (iterated, Prickry, etc.) be viewed in the same (analogous) way? Any reference for the last question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the references here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)#References

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest Andre Scedrov's paper "Forcing and classifying topoi" [Memoirs A.M.S. 48 (1984) No. 295] or the early part of my joint paper with Scedrov, "Freyd's models for the independence of the axiom of choice" [Memoirs A.M.S. 79 (1989), No. 404].